# Why this SQL DELETE query using another query output as WHERE condition go into error?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-delete, rdbms

I am not so into SQL and I have the following problem. I am using MySql

I have a table named **Market_Commodity_Price_Series** and I have to delete some records from this table using a query output as WHERE condition, so I have done something like this:

```
DELETE FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series
WHERE Market_Commodity_Price_Series.id = (SELECT MCPS.id
FROM  Market_Commodity_Price_Series as MCPS
WHERE 
      month(MCPS.price_date) > 3
AND
      year(MCPS.price_date) = 2018)
```

This query

```
(SELECT MCPS.id
FROM  Market_Commodity_Price_Series as MCPS
WHERE 
      month(MCPS.price_date) > 3
AND
      year(MCPS.price_date) = 2018)
```

return n ID that identifies the record that have to be deleted.

The problem is that performing this delete query I obtain this error message:

> ## HY000You can't specify target table 'Market_Commodity_Price_Series' for update in FROM clause

Why? What is the problem? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The message is clear, you can not select and delete from same table. Read baout `Delete .. join`

Comment: The answer is below, though down-voted, you need to copy your subquery to a temp table, and draw your conditional from there.

Comment: This should have work too I think : `SET @id = (SELECT...); DELETE FROM...WHERE...id = @id;`. First you get your id with you SELECT query, then your use the result for your DELETE

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,
it was absolutly simple task:

```
DELETE FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series
WHERE MONTH(price_date) > 3 AND YEAR(price_date) = 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

> DELETE FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series WHERE Market_Commodity_Price_Series.id = (SELECT * FROM(SELECT MCPS.id FROM  Market_Commodity_Price_Series as MCPS WHERE  month(MCPS.price_date) > 3 AND year(MCPS.price_date) = 2018)tblTmp);

The query is basically the same, except the inner select is wrapped inside another select.
The most important thing to note is that the original select has been given an alias “tblTmp“. (The name tblTmp is arbitrary, you can give it any alias name.) 
The alias is important because assigning one will tell MySQL to create a temporary table from this select query. 
The temporary table may then be used as the source criteria for the update statement.

The reason it is wrapped inside another query is because MySQL syntax does not let you assign an alias to a select query when it is part of an update statement. 
So we have to put it inside another query which, I suppose separates it from the update statement.

Comment: The OP does not need a query of this complexity, q.v. the deleted answers and comments.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but I think it should be

```
DELETE * FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series
WHERE [...]
```